# Is it possible to add inertia to iScroll js?

Tags: scroll, smooth-scrolling, iscroll

http://iscrolljs.com/

I'm trying to search but I cannot find anything about adding inertia to iScroll js when we are scrolling it with **mouse wheel** (not when dragging it).

When I use mouse wheel, I'd like it to have momentum or inertia too.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Check this plugin has Inertia.. http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/